# .htaccess redirect whole website structure but leave some of the old structure intact

Tags: .htaccess

I have searched but can't quite find the answer to this exact situation:

My website structure is as follows

**www.example.co.uk/old-folder1/old-folder2/old-page-name**

I needed to redirect the whole structure to:

**www.example.co.uk/new-folder1/old-folder2/old-page-name**

I successfully did this with:

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder1/(.*)$ /new-folder1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

However, if possible for the moment I still want to serve images from the old structure ie.

**www.example.co.uk/old-folder1/old-images-folder/old-image.jpg**

At the moment the above is being rewritten as:

**www.example.co.uk/new-folder1/old-images-folder/old-image.jpg**

Which makes sense but this leads me to my question, is there any way of excluding some of the sub directories in 'old-folder1' from the RewriteRule above so that for example **www.example.co.uk/old-folder1/old-images-folder/old-image.jpg** is still accessible?

I don't have much experience with this but from research I came up with the following but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old-folder1/old-images-folder/.*$
```

I am beginning to think this might not even be possible with the approach I have taken with:

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder1/(.*)$ /new-folder1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Thanks

Entire contents of the .htaccess file at the moment is:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old-folder1/old-images-folder/.*$
RewriteRule ^old-folder1/(.*)$ /new-folder1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: @Croises I have edited showing entire contents of .htaccess file, yes the RewriteCond is just before RewriteRule.

Comment: I think it should work ... :-/

Comment: @Croises - Turns out it does work, a typo crept into my htaccess file, my mistake. Thanks for your comments though as it led to the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder1/(?!old-images-folder)(.*)$ /new-folder1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

HOwever, what's probably happening is that your images are linked using relative URLs, so they may be relatively linked to the "new" images folder.

You should check your links and make sure they're linked correctly to the old path.

Comment: Thanks @JonLin - Although it turns out my original htaccess rules were correct and working - but failed due to a typo (my mistake) - your answer works too and it is more condensed.